# How to sign .apk file using Java swing application

Tags: java, apk, gradlew

I have a Java Swing application that allows the user to select multiple .apk files to be signed with the same key. I tried to use ProcessBuilder to use the signapk.jar to sign but not luck. Any ideas? I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: try from the command line look for guides to do that it is not too complicated

Comment: Dont hesitate. Please do..More details you provide more narrower will be your problem..

Comment: This is the command used to sign an apk:
"java -jar signapk.jar cacert.pem privkey.pem app-debug.apk app-signed.apk"
When run from the command-line it asks for the private key password and creates the signed apk. I am trying to do the same thing except in a Java UI. I am instantiating a ProcessBuilder(pb) and adding the required args to the pb.command() method and then do a "Process p = pb.start();" I am guessing I need a way to inject the password somehow. I am getting no errors or anything so not sure where to look.